# How to wrap images around one image in the center?

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, css

What i am trying to do is to have one main image that will alleyways be in the center of the page, then around that center image to be many images that will wrap around the main image.
Example:
[image]

instead i am just getting them to view like the following picture even when i add a float to said picture.
[image]

Just to put this out there, i am using bootstrap.

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: You might want to check out Flexbox for this: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ — if you need to support older browsers, you can achieve the same effect by using tables.

Comment: Even `flexbox` can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm, that you may use in PHP/SASS to generate classes.

```
var output = '';

// Rows.

    for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++) {

    // Cells.
    for (var x = 0; x < 14; x++) {

        // Clear the area for the main image.
        if (y < 7 && x > 2 && x < 11) {
            output += '0';
        } else {
            output += '1';
        }

        if (x === 13) {
            output += '\n';
        }
    }
}

// Output.
11100000000111
11100000000111
11100000000111
11100000000111
11100000000111
11100000000111
11100000000111
11111111111111
11111111111111
```

Please see the example I have built with Bootstrap. Just make sure that the aspect ratio of images is the same.

```css
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.margin-b--10px {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.padding-lr--5px {
  padding-left: 5px !important;
  padding-right: 5px !important;
}

.padding-lr--10px {
   padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<header>
  <div class="container well">
    <h1>Header</h1>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div class="row">
        <script>
          var count = 24;
          while (count) {
            document.write('<div class="col-xs-4 margin-b--10px padding-lr--5px"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/eeeeee?text=Column+1"></div>');
            count--;
          }
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 padding-lr--5px"> 
      <div class="margin-b--10px"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x700"></div>
      
       <div class="row padding-lr--10px">
        <script>
var count = 12;
while(count) { document.write('<div class="col-xs-2 margin-b--10px padding-lr--5px"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100/333333?text=Column+1"></div>');
count--;
}
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class=" col-xs-3 ">
       <div class="row ">
        <script>
var count = 24;
while(count) { document.write('<div class="col-xs-4 margin-b--10px padding-lr--5px "><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100?text=Column+1 "></div>');
count--;
}
        </script>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean this works but is there a way of doing this where all the small images are together and not split up into 3 groups?

Comment: @JonAugood yes, you can do that by hardcoding the coordinates for every block with `position: absolute`, I would generate that kind of styling with SASS. There are also a JavaScript library called [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), id does something like that dynamically, but I can't guarantee that it will solve the task.

Comment: @JonAugood here is a SASS example I have made with the core idea of that approach http://sassmeister.com/gist/caf4133ac9afef4b9129

Comment: The thing is how easy would this be to put into a php script that doesn't have an exact amount of images, it could have from 2 to even 56. [this is what i would love to get in the end](http://i.imgur.com/2xMUcc6.png)

Comment: Im sorry for being an idiot but how would I put the JavaScript and SASS with the HTML together? Many thanks for the help BTW it means alot!

Comment: @JonAugood sorry for confusion, I have used javascript just to illustrate an example of algorithm. For the starters you need to use that algorithm in PHP to produce HTML of images, with classses like `image-x-y`. Then you can use [sassmeister.com](http://sassmeister.com/) to reuse the same algorithm for generating the styling for positioning of those blocks.